# Incorrect values received from legacy soap client to .net server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, legacy

I have a problem with getting correct values from a legacy client into my new wcf soap web service.

I am not allowed to change the client. The client sends this code to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <setScannerLiveViewBounds xmlns="http://ejb.enrollment.snabbfoto.se">
            <in0 xmlns="">
                <y>414</y>
                <width>320</width>
                <height>340</height>
                <x>125</x>
            </in0>
            <in1 xmlns="">20130403</in1>
        </setScannerLiveViewBounds>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The new server has the following interfaces:

```
[OperationContract(Action = ""), DataContractFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc)]
void setScannerLiveViewBounds([MessageParameter(Name = "in0")]RectangleMV inBounds, [MessageParameter(Name = "in1")]String inLock);

[DataContract(Name = "Rectangle")]
public class RectangleMV
{
        [DataMember]
        public int x { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int y { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int width { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int height { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I only receive 0 for x, y, width and height when it reaches my code. I get the correct value for "in1".

Comment: Your service reference is updated Right?

Comment: Yes. But I had to build it by hand. I could not use the old wsdl to generate my server.